# getUserIdentityTokenAsync method keeps returning obsolete identity token until 30 minutes when EdgeHtml used as browser in Outlook add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We are using getUserIdentityTokenAsync method provided by Microsoft to fetch the identity token for our custom Outlook add-in.

Whenever we are updating the manifest file in Outlook to install the add-in, getUserIdentityTokenAsync keeps returning obsolete identity token with old aud value instead of updated one. getUserIdentityTokenAsync method returns the correct updated token only after 30 minutes of installing new manifest. This issue is only occurring where EdgeHTML is used as browser for add-in . For Outlook where Chromium is used as browser, it is working fine(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins). Can you please look into the issue & let us know if there is any recent change done by Microsoft in its behavior & what is the reason if done or is it an issue?

Comment: You need to [post this as an issue to the OfficeJS repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) on GitHub instead.

Comment: Are you trying it on Outlook desktop or OWA?

Comment: Its Outlook Desktop

Comment: Hi, @googlecalendart - Can you provide the following information?
1. What version of Outlook are you running?
2. Are you able to reproduce the issue at all in OWA or only on win32?
3. Can you clarify what this means "getUserIdentityTokenAsync method returns the correct updated token only after 30 minutes of installing new manifest". Does this means that it doesn't work correctly for the first 30 minutes and then corrects itself?

Thank you

Comment: This appears to be the same post: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2830 let's follow up there so answers/responses are consolidated.